# Sending data to a node in CANoe simulation

Tags: tcp, udp, ethernet, capl, canoe

I am trying to set up a simulation of an Ethernet net work in CANoe. This network has two nodes ("input" and "result"). The input node should receive a data stream from the "outside", e.g. another program on my computer. The idea was sending simple data (e.g. 101010 as bits) via TCP/UDP to the input node. This node then transfers these bits to the result node, which simply outputs the received data. So much for the basic setup.

What I am not able to accomplish is the connection from the outside into the CANoe simulation aka the input node. After hours of reading the CANoe help I am still not sure if that is even possible. So has anyone tried something similiar like this or has an idea how to approach this?

I hope it is clear what I want to achieve. I am relatively new to CANoe, so maybe my complete approach is wrong? Some input or alternative ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you configure CANoe‘s Ethernet channels?

Comment: I configured them for a usage on localhost (disabled the usage of TCP/IP stack), added a CAPL example from CANoe help. WIth this a creation of  an UDP communication is possible. But maybe there a better solutions?

Comment: Basically two options: Disable CANoe's TCP/IP stack and use the stack of the operating system (this is what you did). The other option is to use CANoe's TCP/IP stack and add an adapter that is exposed to your operating system. What makes more sense depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible. CANoe allows usage of CANoe TCP/IP Stack to isolate Ethernet Communication from ECUs from Windows/OS ethernet communication. To use operating system stack :

In CANoe> Simulation Setup> TCP/IP Stack :

Select the Ethernet network used, set TCP/IP Stack Configuration for the particular network should be selected as "No TCP/IP Stack, use network of operating system"

This way CANoe will have access to windows system network adapters.